# Apex Invocable Method to change case Owner Id to user Id

Tags: apex, process-builder

I've build a process Builder to change the current Case owner Id(Queue ID) to current user Id login to the case. The code I have is:

```
public with sharing class CaseOwerIdvsUserId {
    @InvocableMethod(label='OwnerIdvsUserId' description='swap the owner id which is the Queue Id with the session user id')
    public static void getCases(List<Id> CasesId)
    {
        List<case> ids = [select id from case where ownerid = '00517000001RUur'];
        ids = UserInfo.getUserId();
    }
}
```

But I think I might be implementing this wrong.

Comment: Are you getting an error message of any kind? Or are you just looking for feedback on the code you've written?

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding about the nature of the `OwnerId` field. What is the **end result** you are trying to achieve? At a high level, please.

Comment: Replace the current owner of(it's a queue I'd) with a user ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need here is soomething like this

```
public with sharing class CaseOwerIdvsUserId {
    @InvocableMethod(label='OwnerIdvsUserId' description='swap the owner id which is the Queue Id with the session user id')
    public static void getCases(List<Id> CasesIdList)
    {
        List<case> caseList = new List<case>();
        // add all case in list
        for(case cas : [selectId, ownerId from case where Id IN: CasesIdList])
        {
             if(cas.getSObjectType() == Group.SObjectType())
                 caseList.add(new case(Id= cas.Id, OwnerId = userinfo.getuserId()));
        }
        // update the records
        update caseList;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to check if it's a queue-owned case, though...

Comment: @sfdcfox yes I should put a check here.

Comment: why use : (new case(Id = caseId, OwnerId = userinfo.getuserId()); the case already exists?

Comment: @Templar "new case" means to create a new variable in memory. I'd suggest you start with the [trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en) to learn more about how code works.

Comment: ? if `caseId` is a `Case.Id`, how can it ever start with `00G`? Shouldn't you be querying for `Case.ownerId`?

Comment: @cropredy OwnerId can be a 005 or 00G-- a Queue. Although, I find that I prefer to not use key prefixes, but instead: `if(caseId.getSObjectType() == Group.SObjectType)`. This makes the code easier to read.

Comment: @sfdcfox -- I agree on `getSobjectType()==...` but `Case.Id` is the ID of a `Case` Sobject, it is different than `Case.OwnerId` - the latter is what has to be tested against `Group.sobjectType`.